# How to free memory allocated by ImageMagick GetImageHistogram()?

Tags: imagemagick

I'm using `ColorPacket *GetImageHistogram(const Image *image, ...)` to extract an histogram. I see IM sources and found, that GetImageHistogram allocates memory via:

```
  histogram=(ColorPacket *) AcquireQuantumMemory((size_t) cube_info->colors,
    sizeof(*histogram));
```

How should I free this memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To free memory allocated with `AcquireQuantumMemory`, use `RelinquishMagickMemory`:

```
histogram = RelinquishMagickMemory(histogram);
```

See the [API documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/api/memory.php#RelinquishMagickMemory). This function always returns `NULL`.